# Analytics using PYTHON

Tags: python, analytics

I would like to Learn About DATA Analytics.

Where to start it?
Where I can find the concepts about analytics?

What are all the Frameworks in PYTHON used for analytics?
Which could be good for my career(PYTHON or R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where to start it? Where i can find the concepts about analytic?

Data analytic/analysis is a huge concepts, but a good way to start is find a problem (data to analyse) and solve it. My suggestion is to buy a book. For example if you like to use python i suggested: "Python for Data Analysis".

> What are all the Frameworks in PYTHON used for analytics?
>   As suggested in the other answer Numpy, Pandas and Matplotlib. Furthermore, Scipy more useful for Statistical problem. Another framework really interesting is scikit-learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/.

Ps: a good framework that include all the former package is called Anaconda

Comment: Thanks for your Response.
As for as i understood below 3 libraries are highly used for Analytics

NumPy,
SciPy,
matplotlib

And i came to know below libraries are used in machine learning

Mlpy,
Orange,
scikit-learn,
Pandas

what are all the advantages of libraries(Mlpy,Orange,scikit-learn,Pandas)?

Do i have to learn all or any one is enough?

Which is te best in machine learning?


Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Depend what do you need to do, for sure some are more specific for particular domain. Scikit-learn I can tell, since I use it, is almost complete. You can find the the most used Machine Learning techniques. By the way, what do you need to learn is depending on which problem do you need to solve. As I told you before, Scikit-learn is a safe bet.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its really Help full. 
I am very new to this. I am asking one more question out of curiosity.
For analytics and Machine learning Directly i can start learning scikit-learn or do i ve to learn SciPy or Numpy first?

Comment: You are going to see that they are connected. I mean, to use Scikit-learn you must no some syntax of Numpy and Scipy.

Comment: Hi Andrea, I got another Question. Is Python useful in Hadoop? Where We Use Python in Hadoop? What Hadoop tools are mainly used for Data Analytics?

Comment: Hadoop is a framework for Big Data analysis, write in Java. Now, Python is neither useful or useless for Hadoop. Hadoop is "something" used when, for example, you cannot fit your data in a single Hard Disk. Then, Hadoop distribute your process in cluster of machines.

Comment: Any Tools Like HIVE, HBase, Etc are Used For Analytics?

Comment: Normally many people use Hadoop itself but there are many "tools" that run over it. For example: PIG, Spark (you can use Python ) etc.                                                                    BTW you can use Hadoop in python (e.g. Hadoopy).

Comment: Yes, also HIVE HBase and yes they are use for analytic. Let me say, use Hadoop itself is pretty difficult but with one of this "tools" is easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are vast choices for data analysis in Python. There are many frameworks which ensure that you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Some of the major of them are:

1) NumPy: It is a Python library providing easy access to arrays, matrix operations and linear algebra.(You may also consider SciPy)

2) Pandas: It is a library which provides you 2D datasets or dataframes to store data. They are handy at times.

3) Matplotlib: It is a great library for making and plotting 2D graphs. It has the ability to make graphs and histograms with just a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your Response.
As for as i understood below 3 libraries are highly used for Analytics

NumPy,
SciPy,
matplotlib

And i came to know below libraries are used in machine learning

Mlpy,
Orange,
scikit-learn,
Pandas

what are all the advantages of libraries(Mlpy,Orange,scikit-learn,Pandas)?

Do i have to learn all or any one is enough?

Which is te best in machine learning?


Thanks,
Arun